# Can I tell Google Cloud SQL to restore my backup to a completely different database?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

Since there is a nightly backup of SQL we are wondering of a good way to restore this backup to a different database in the same MySQL server instance.  We have prod_xxxx for all our production databases AND we have staging_xxxx for all our staging databases (yes not that good in that they are all on the same mysql instance right now).

Anyways, we would love to restore all tables/constraints/etc and data from prod_incomingdb to staging_incomingdb.  Is this possible in cloud SQL?

Comment: I am not certain what you are asking. You can replicate your SQL instance and then break the mirroring providing you with an independent copy. Otherwise, you are limited to export/import of the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is over a productive instance I recommend you to perform a backup before start, in order to avoid any data corruption.

To clone a database within the same instance, there is not a direct way to perform the task (this is a missing feature on MySQL).

I followed this path in order to successfully clone a database within same MySQL Cloud SQL instance.

1.- Create a dump of the desired database using the Google Cloud Console (Web UI) by follow these [steps](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/import-export/exporting#exporting_data_to_a_csv_file_in)

*it is very important to only dump the **desired database** in format SQL, please not select multiple databases on the dump.

After finish the process, the dump will be available in a Google Cloud Storage Bucket.

2.- Download the dump file to a Compute Engine VM or to any local machine with linux.

3.- please replace the database name (the old one) in the `USE` clauses.

I used this sed command over my downloaded dump to change the names of the databases

```
 sed -i 's/USE `employees`;/USE `emp2`;/g' employees.sql
```

*this can take some seconds depending the size of your file.

4.- Upload the updated file to the Cloud storage bucket.

5.- Create a new empty database on your Cloud SQL instance, in this case my target instance  is called `emp2`.

6.- Import the modified dump by following these [steps](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/import-export/importing#importing_data_from_a_sql_dump_file_in)

Comment: You can mount the storage bucket onto a compute engine and work on it as if it was a file on an additional disk I think. Need to double check.

Answer (score 0):

I could not figure out the nightly backups as it seems to restore an entire instance.  I think the answer to the above is no.  I did find out that I can export and then import (not exactly what I wanted though as I didn't want to be exporting our DB during the day but for now, we may go with that and automate a nightly export later).